# Angular 2 selector with namespace

Tags: angularjs, selector, angular2-directives

Is there any way to define selector for elements like `<ns:element>`?

With `selector: 'ns:element'` Angular 1 was able to get only elements which fully match selector (`ns:element`), but Angular 2 match both `element` and `ns:element`.

To be more precise, it's look like Angular 2, ignores `ns:` segment.

I've tried selectors like `ns\:element`, `ns\\:element` but this doesn't help.